# Library not loaded: @rpath/libpng16.16.dylib

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

when I call `mpl_toolkits.basemap`, I get the following error, anyone can help?

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/pegah/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/ft2font.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libpng16.16.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/pegah/anaconda3/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
Reason: Incompatible library version: libfreetype.6.dylib requires version 51.0.0 or later, but libpng16.16.dylib provides version 49.0.0
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem, and it fixed by updating the libgdal (you can update everything by doing: conda update --all), it seems the reason is the incompatible library - libfreetype.

Comment: Thank you. I’ll try it. I could solve it temporarily by creating new environment but still I don’t have access to some libraries such as rasterio and fiona.

Comment: Perhaps try to install `fiona` using conda.

Comment: Example `conda install -c conda-forge basemap fiona`

Comment: Great. This worked for me - `conda install -c conda-forge basemap fiona`. Thanks!